# Login with Twitter using twython-django

Tags: django, twitter, twython

I want the user to have the option to login using his twitter account to get his timeline. I am using twython-django package.
here's my code
views.py

```
def login(request):
twitter = Twython(settings.TWITTER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_SECRET)

# Request an authorization url to send the user to...
callback_url =' http://127.0.0.1:8000/cloud/twitter_authenticated/'
auth_props = twitter.get_authentication_tokens(callback_url)

# Then send them over there, durh.
request.session['request_token'] = auth_props

request.session['next_url'] = request.GET.get('next',None)

return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_props['auth_url'])


def twitter_authenticated(request):
"""A user gets redirected here after hitting Twitter and authorizing your app to use their data.
This is the view that stores the tokens you want
for querying data. Pay attention to this.
"""
# Now that we've got the magic tokens back from Twitter, we need to exchange
# for permanent ones and store them...
oauth_token = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token']
oauth_token_secret = request.session['request_token']['oauth_token_secret']
twitter = Twython(settings.TWITTER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_SECRET,
                  oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

# Retrieve the tokens we want...
authorized_tokens = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(request.GET['oauth_verifier'])

# If they already exist, grab them, login and redirect to a page displaying stuff.
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=authorized_tokens['screen_name'])
except User.DoesNotExist:
    # We mock a creation here; no email, password is just the token, etc.
    user = User.objects.create_user(authorized_tokens['screen_name'], "fjdsfn@jfndjfn.com", authorized_tokens['oauth_token_secret'])
    profile = TwitterProfile()
    profile.user = user
    profile.oauth_token = authorized_tokens['oauth_token']
    profile.oauth_secret = authorized_tokens['oauth_token_secret']
    profile.save()

user = authenticate(
    username=authorized_tokens['screen_name'],
    password=authorized_tokens['oauth_token_secret']
)
login(request, user)
redirect_url = request.session.get('next_url', redirect_url)

HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

I'am getting this error:
"Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), b'Could not authenticate you.'".

Any idea how to solve this problem?